# How To create a report using data from Excel in Word Template

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Summary: 
I have to fill in a report using data from Excel in Word Template.
Problem:
I am trying to write a macro which will search some variables in pre-defined template (doc) and replace these variables with data from excel. The variables are nothing but some text like <-Date->, <-Author-> (self-created). 
There are also some Tables and Sections that needs to be duplicated from the Word Template depending on the Excel Data.
For Example
I’ll need to make 3 more Sections for Dates. Because 
Word
1.<-Date->

Excel
03-10-2013
04-10-2013
05-10-2013

After Macro
1.  03-10-2013

1. 04-10-2013
2. 05-10-2013

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need macros at all for this, MailMerge works extremely well to import and auto generate word documents from Excel for this very reason - and it's built right into Word:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-HA102809678.aspx